# Iterating through Unicode array for float values

Tags: python

I have an array of Unicode strings with certain numbers that I need to pull out and save as floats. What would be the easiest way to iterate through this array for the low temp, current temp, and high temp? Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import numpy as np

#Arkansas State Plant Board Weather Web data
url1 = "http://170.94.200.136/weather/Inversion.aspx"
response1 = requests.get(url1)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.content)
table1 = soup1.find("table", id="MainContent_GridView1")

data1 = pd.read_html(str(table1))[0]

array1 = np.array(data1[0:5])
```

Comment: Why is Unicode relevant here?

Comment: This doesn't show an example of what the OP has tried.

Answer (score 1):

First, modify your code to parse the DataFrame header correctly.

`data1 = pd.read_html(str(table1),header=0)[0]`

Then, convert the columns you need to float, for example.

`data1['Low Temp (°F)'] = data1['Low Temp (°F)'].astype(float)`.

You can select a subset of columns in Pandas like this:

```
data1[['Station','Low Temp (°F)','High Temp (°F)','Current Temp (°F)']].head()

    Station Low Temp (°F)   High Temp (°F)  Current Temp (°F)
0   Arkansas    74.9    88.9    88.9
1   Ashley  75.0    92.0    91.6
2   Bradley -9.6    91.5    91.4
3   Chicot  -40.2   -40.1   -40.2
4   Cleveland   73.7    91.1    91.0
```

You could then use `iterrows()` to iterate through the DataFrame.

Comment: When I try to convert the columns to float, I get this: 
KeyError: 'Low Temp (\xc2\xb0F)'

Comment: The code works in Python 3, you didn't mention your Python version.

Try renaming the columns and remove the degree symbol: 

`data1.columns = ['Station', 'Low Temp (F)', ... ]`